# Best way to create a hole in a mesh?

Tags: mesh, geometry

I'm modelling a minigolf hole but when i create the hole with boolean modifier i see a little drop around it.
This cause the ball in the game not rolling straight as it should.
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Please add images to your post to show what you have so far.

Comment: Here's a link to a video showing different hole-cutting techiniques https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bc52fcrHvAA. Obiuvsly there is not a "best", each one has its pros and cons, each one is preferrable for one situation and not for others. Could you better describe yours? Maybe with a gif/video/blendfile...

Comment: Does "the ball in the game" mean this is a BGE question? Or are you using some other game engine? I'm guessing the boolean approach is not the best solution for your task. Maybe creating a hole with proper topology (maybe an octagonal hole with holding edges, subsurfed?) could be a better solution? You haven't provided many details about your geometry. Uploading a .blend would help us to help you.

Comment: Trying other hole-cutting techniques i've found a possible solution to my problem. Thank all anyway